# Social conflicts in economic growth models

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, economic-growth, social-welfare, social-choice

I'm highly interested in theories and models which explain how do social conflicts influence economic growth. 
What papers on the topic can you recommend? I was searching for some seminal and most important articles just to get into, but there is so much of them. 
Would it be okay to start from: Benhabib J., "Social conflict and growth"? 
Thank you.